# Passing local variables to a view from controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller

I am not able for some reason to pass local variables to the show view...

In my controller i have simply:

```
def show
  render template: "books/show", :resource => "Some text"
end
```

In my view i print the following:

```
<h1>My local variable text: <%= resource %></h1>
```

And i am getting the following message:

```
undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#<Class:0x00000118ebce90>:0x00000118ec3498>
```

I've tried the following syntaxes in the controller:

```
render template: "books/show", locals: { resource: "Some text" }
render template: "books/show", locals: { resource => "Some text" }
render template: "books/show", :locals => { resource: "Some text" }
render template: "books/show", :locals => { resource => "Some text" }
```

Without any luck...

Any clues ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to pass local variables instead of instance variables? I am assuming "Some Text" is a place holder because otherwise it would make way more sense for this to be in the view. I pass locals to partials but instance variables to base views. Locals implies it is only needed locally and can be cleaned up afterwards. Otherwise here is my 2 seconds of [Googling your question](http://thepugautomatic.com/2013/05/locals/)

Comment: No it's more complicated than that! "Some text" is just for illustration... I'm passing different objects depending from where i'm calling the template. To do so, i have no choice but to add the capacity to define local variable for the view...

Comment: For instance, i'm calling the template either from a controller, or from a decorator. Also this template is used for different Classes as they are very similar in many aspects...

Comment: Well I would advise against asking a broad question like this then and specify what the overall problem is that way people can help with solving this as well as offer design advice. If I have to share view aspects I usually tear these off into partials and pass a more generically named object to handle the similarities but that's just me. Really I would post the actual problem and people will be more willing to help

Answer (score 14):

## Passing Data from the Controller to the View

Here's a NovelController class, to be put into `app/ controllers/novel_controller.rb.`

```
class NovelController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @title = 'Shattered View: A Novel on Rails'
      end
end
```

Since this is the Novel controller and the index action, the corresponding view is in `app/views/novel/index.html.erb`

```
<h1><%= @title %></h1>
```

**Output:**

```
Shattered View: A Novel on Rails
```

The view is interpreted after `NovelController#index` is run. Here's what the view can and can't access:

- It can access the instance variables `@title`, because they've been defined on the `NovelController` object by the time `NovelController#index` finishes running.
- It can call instance methods of the instance variables `@title`.

Answer (score 10):

I think it should be like

`render 'books/show', :locals => {:resource => 'Some text'}`

It works for me

Answer (score 7):

## TL; DR

### `render locals: { resource: "Some text" }`

### Full

First I am wondering why would you need the `template:`. Are you on Rails 2.x? If not, then the `:template` option is no longer required. You should be able to get along fine with just

`render "books/show"`

Second do you need to specify the template? What is the controller you want to render from? If that's `BooksController`, then you don't need the template path either, which makes the line being just

`render`

That's without the variables yet. Now, I just checked, and a simple:

`render locals: { resource: "Some text" }`

as well as:

`render 'books/show', locals: { resource: "Some text" }`

works for me just fine. Maybe earlier Rails versions treated 'resource' as some kind of a keyword? Don't know, but the above Worksforme™ in both forms.

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass local variables from a controller to a view. What you could do is define it as an instance variable and then it would automatically be available in the view.

```
@resource = @book
```

If you want to pass entirely different objects, then just define those instance variables differently.

Comment: Actually you surely can pass local variables from controller to a view. Defining instance variables is a common but not the only way.

Comment: @silverdr I would love to see a demonstration of this.

Comment: Sure. A working example is in my answer deeeeeep down below :-) To add to this - even the so called "Rails best practices" complain about using instance variables in the views instead of local variables. I don't actually agree with that and believe that instance variables have their valid place in the views but if someone wants to comply with their recommendations, it is surely possible to pass local variables.

Answer (score 4):

You can get it as follows. All gives the same result. Here is the [reference](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) link.

```
render action: :show , locals: { resource: "Some text"}
render :show , locals: { resource: "Some text"}
render locals: { resource: "Some text"}
```