# Rails 5: Check returned enum value in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I am struggling to check returned enum value.
In models/roles.rb I have enums:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  enum general: { seller: 1, buyer: 2, seller_buyer: 3}, _suffix: true
  enum dashboard: { denied: 0, viewer: 1, editer: 2, creater: 3, deleter: 4}, _suffix: true
```

In controllers/dashboard_controller.rb I have this:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def dashboard_1
    @roles = current_user.roles
    Role.select(:dashboard).where(user_id: current_user)
    if
     flash.now[:error] = "You can do whatever want!"
    else 
     flash.now[:error] = "Only view!"
   end
 end
```

In console I can get this:

```
Role.select(:dashboard).where(:user_id => 1)
Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles"."dashboard" FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]`=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Role id: nil, dashboard: "deleter">]>`
```

where dashboard: "deleter" is my desired outcome.
**I want to check in controller that if user role for dashboard is "deleter"** (flash.now says "You can do whatever want!"

### Please, any suggestions how to do this? Many thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is my controllers/dashboard_controller.rb

```
def dashboard_1
  @roles = current_user.roles
    if @roles.any? { |role| role.deleter_dashboard? }
      flash.now[:error] = "You are deleter!"
    elsif @roles.any? { |role| role.viewer_dashboard? }
      flash.now[:error] = "You are viewer!"
    else 
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end
```

In dashboard_1.html.erb I try to show "New campaign" button only if user is "deleter" for Dashboard section:

```
<% if @roles.deleter_dashboard? %>
   <%= link_to new_campaign_path(@campaign), {method: 'get', class: 'btn btn-w-m btn-primary'} do %>New campaign
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However I keep getting this error - *undefined method deleter_dashboard? for Role::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy*
**How do I make it working right?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could just use the instance variable `@roles` that you've initialized

```
if @roles.any? { |role| role.deleter_dashboard? }
  flash.now[:error] = "You can do whatever want!"
else 
  flash.now[:error] = "Only view!"
end
```

You should be able to `role.deleter_dashboard?` according to the [documentation of Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Comment: You're welcome. Also - I don't really see the full scope of the functionality that you're trying to implement but I guess you don't have to initialize an instance variable `@roles` for this purpose, use `roles` instead (considering that you are not acessing this information across the controller methods afterwards).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In ideal world I was thinking to cache all current_user roles at login. `Role.where(:user_id => 1)` finds all roles for 1st user.  It is single row with multiple columns (enums in cells) from Roles table. With this info in cache I would check current_user roles when accessing any section of my app. Do you have any idea of how to do this? Any hint would be great.

Comment: You definitely could cache roles at login althogh I'm not really sure if that's necessary. I don't think there would be much performance gain (if any) with the utilization of roles cache, in the end you have to query the DB at login anyway and I really doubt having one query here and there would hurt your apps performance. Don't try to overcomplicate things, optimize when you need to :). Btw you might want to check [pundit gem](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) for user authorization and maybe even [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)

Comment: Yes, I will not do the cache thing. Not sure if I need Rolify as I can do this role checking query for each section of app. I'm trying to implement Pundit, however something is not working properly. So I am experimenting without Pundit: `<% role.creater_campaigns? or role.deleter_campaigns? %>
        <%= link_to "New campaign", new_campaign_path(@campaign) %>
    <% end %>`   but I get  _expecting end-of-input _  error

Comment: You are probably missing an `if` in the first ebmedded Ruby conditional and it should look like this `<% if role.creater_campaigns? || role.deleter_campaigns? %>`. I substituted the `or` for `||` as you can see. The `and` or `or` operators are usually used for control flow ([explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby#answer-10648796)) and [some people even discourage you to use it at all](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or).

Comment: I'm trying to implement it, however I keep getting error: _undefined local variable or method role_                  My code:  `<ul class="new_campaigns">`
    `<% if role.creater_campaigns? || role.deleter_campaigns? %>`
        `<%= link_to new_campaign_path(@campaign), {method: 'get', class: 'btn btn-w-m btn-primary'} do %>New campaign`
        `<% end %>`
    `<% end %>`
`</ul>`  Please, can you check what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you to read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730570/passing-local-variables-to-a-view-from-controller#answer-39828730) as I would not like to create duplicate posts. You can't expect a local variable to be accessible from view, you've got to initialize an instance variable, in this case `@role`. Initialize it in your controller action method and then use it in it's view (`<% if @role.creater_campaigns? || @role.deleter_campaigns? %>`). Your embedded code could work in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672454/passing-parameters-to-partial-view) though

Comment: Thank you, I read those posts and tried to implement both ways, however it does not work so far. Please, can you check my post update here above? I updated what I have in controller and view and what error do I get.

Comment: I see that you are struggling with some pretty basic things, I highly advise you to complete [a proper Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/). You can not call `deleter_dashboard?` on `@role`, (which should, btw, by the most common conventions, be called `@roles`) because it's and instance of `Role::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, which is **not** an instance of `class Role` on instance of which could the `deleter_dashboard?` be invoked. Also remove `Role.select(:dashboard).where(user_id: current_user)`, it's completely useless as you are not assigning its result

Comment: Yes, I am working with that tutorial as it is really great. I am trying to follow Harlts suggestion not to use too many gems and try to do as much as possible on my own. To be honest I reverted from `@roles` to `@role` as I have been totaly lost since I got that error. I have replaced with `@roles` and removed `select` line (see my update above), however I keep getting that error. Please, help!